# Extract from string using regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need to extract a piece of a string. I have to extract from `system.cpu.util[,idle]` or `net.if.out[eth2]` respectively `idle` and `eth2`.

I don't know how to detect correcty `[` and `]` 
Can someone help me?

Comment: You need to escape [ and ] as they are meta characters use \\[ and \\]

Answer (score 1):

here is the manual for [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

```
var= net.if.out[eth2]
preg_match('/\[,?(.*?)\]/', $var, $match);
print match[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Since [ and ] mean something special in a regexp, you have to put a \ in front of them, or preg_match won't take them literally. Same with your dots.

Comment: A regex like `preg_match('.*\[\?P<test>\w+\].*', $test, $matches);` should work, shouldn't it ? It doesn't. What do I wrong ?

Comment: nor this : `preg_match('\.*\[\?P<test>\w+\]\.*', $item->name, $matches);`

Comment: @Leitoo0: You need delimiter: `preg_match('/.*\[\(?P<test>\w+)\].*/', $test, $matches);`, and named capturing group is `(?P<name>pattern)`

Comment: @nhahtdh With this `'/.*\[(?P<test>\.*)\].*/'` I catch nothing, is it normal ?

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
preg_match('/\[,?(.*?)\]/', $test, $matches);
```